# Merging feature within cells in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, features, cell-statistics

I'm dealing with a global fire map (vector map, polygons don't overlap), each cell contains the number of fires occurred in this area over the past 20 years.

I'm trying to sum up the value of "fid" in each cell. "Fid" are in the same format, what I'm interested in is the "nfires" in each Fid, which records the number of fires in this cell.

Take this cell for example, there is two Fid, and each contains one fire, which sums up as two for this cell.

[image]

Is there a way to do this for all the cells? I feel it shouldn't be too complicated but I'm confused by the features in groups.

Comment: Hi! At first I thought you had a raster map, but the way it is described, it seems like a vector map with overlapping polygons, can you confirm this? (preferably by editing the original post)- also, you say it is a global map, is it possible to download it somewhere, that would make it easier to test and describe what you need to do.